# How to Use Multiple Predicate ( Condition ) in one AWS WAF Rule with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I 'm able to create multiple condition at one AWS WAF Classic rule from the AWS Console by just click the the "***Add  condition***" button.

[image: Text]

So how can I define multiple condition (predicate) at one waf rule with terraform?

I tested with this :

```
resource "aws_wafregional_rule" "wafregional_ip_whitelist_rule" {
  depends_on  = ["aws_wafregional_ipset.wafregional_ip_whitelist", "aws_wafregional_ipset.wafregional_vpn_ip_whitelist"]
  name        = "internal_ip_whitelist_rule"
  metric_name = "WAFWhitelistRule"
  predicate {
    data_id = ["${aws_wafregional_ipset.wafregional_ip_whitelist.id}","${aws_wafregional_ipset.wafregional_vpn_ip_whitelist.id}"]
    negated = false
    type    = "IPMatch"
  }
}
```

But predicate.data_id is not a list :

`Error: aws_wafregional_rule.wafregional_ip_whitelist_rule: predicate.0.data_id must be a single value, not a list`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have multiple predicates for a single WAF rule you must specify the `predicate` block multiple times:

```
resource "aws_wafregional_ipset" "ipset_1" {
  name = "tfIPSet1"

  ip_set_descriptor {
    type  = "IPV4"
    value = "192.0.7.0/24"
  }
}

resource "aws_wafregional_ipset" "ipset_2" {
  name = "tfIPSet2"

  ip_set_descriptor {
    type  = "IPV4"
    value = "10.0.0.0/24"
  }
}

resource "aws_wafregional_rule" "wafrule" {
  name        = "tfWAFRule"
  metric_name = "tfWAFRule"

  predicate {
    type    = "IPMatch"
    data_id = aws_wafregional_ipset.ipset_1.id
    negated = false
  }

  predicate {
    type    = "IPMatch"
    data_id = aws_wafregional_ipset.ipset_2.id
    negated = false
  }
}
```

This would create a single rule that has an allow/deny based on both IP sets specified.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but do both predicates have to be the same type? (like in the example: "IPMatch" ) Or I can have 1 be "IPMatch" and 1 "RegexMatch" for example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, here is an example of a rule with 2 conditions:

```
 rule {
    name     = "AllowPath"
    priority = 1

    action {
      allow {}
    }

    statement {

      and_statement {
        statement {
          regex_pattern_set_reference_statement {
            arn = aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set.regex_pattern_set_path.arn

            field_to_match {
              uri_path {}
            }

            text_transformation {
              priority = 2
              type     = "NONE"
            }
          }
        }

        statement {
          regex_pattern_set_reference_statement {
            arn = aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set.regex_pattern_set_example.arn

            field_to_match {
              single_header {
                name = "my_header"
              }
            }

            text_transformation {
              priority = 2
              type     = "NONE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "AllowPath"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }
```

Basically in this case I'm allowing to access to certain path if has an specific header, but to simplify the example you should follow this structure to have multiple conditions:

```
rule {
    name     = "my_rule"
    priority = 1

    action {
      allow {}
    }

    statement {
      and_statement {
        statement {

        ### STATEMENT 1

        }

        statement {

        ### STATEMENT 2

        }
      }
    }
}
```